# Send different event confirmation emails

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, message-templates

I have setup 2 different events. I would like to send different confirmation emails for the events with the relevant information. This hasn't been an issue before because I have only ever ran 1 event at a time and have edited the Events - Registration Confirmation message template with the relevant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make two different Message Templates yourself and use CiviRules (also requires Email API extension) to send out the correct one based on the Event someone registers for.

If you need payment details as well then make your default CiviCRM Event Registration template just contain the default bits like profile and payment/receipt details.

The second Email via CiviRules/Email API will contain the Event specific information.

Comment: Thanks Karin. This worked well, apart from 1 problem. A user has the option to register for 2 different events within a webform. When they register for both events the email trigger to set off twice and they receive 2 emails. If they only register for 1 event then they receive 1 email. It's the same email for both events. So they only need to receive it once. This might be out of the scope for this question, if so I will create a one.

Comment: That will be fine. It’s actually how things work when I sign my kids up for summer camps at the University (I get Email per kid / per camp and I end up with way too many parking passes :-));

Comment: I thought that this is how it's expected to work. I have an event where users can choose pre booked flights, other travel options and events  (each being an event/ticket so ticket sales can be limited). These users might get in excess of 6 emails, which might be too many. Your message put me onto another solution. To use Drupal webform core email function. Seems to be working pretty well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I did not know you were use Drupal webform when I answered your Q; in a nutshell: use Drupal HTML mail config to make one great looking here are all the options your picked email; If there is a payment with the form -> since that gets processed by CiviCRM post form submission -> you still need to send the Transaction Receipt from CiviCRM (so 2 Emails). At the time the Drupal HTML mail goes out you don’t have a Transaction receipt yet.